# Unable to deploy docker container from dockerhub to aws ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have created a python application with a pipeline that after pushing to github, containerizes the project and pushes to dockerhub. The docker container runs successfully locally but I want to deploy it to aws ECS EC2 launch type (because of free tier) so I create a cluster, Task definition pointing to the dockerhub registry, ASG, ALB and try to create a service or task.
However, on creating the service, cloudfront keeps rolling back during EC2 service creation. If I setup a task then it gets stuck on provisioning.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

**Compute configuration:**
[image]

**Task definition**
[image]

**Cloudfront events**
[image]

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

**Task definition resources**
[image]

**Cluster infrastructure**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your image; instead, it arises from the configuration of your CPU and memory. Please allocate the appropriate CPU and memory resources to your task definition. Additionally, ensure that your EC2 instance has sufficient capacity to handle the task.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do in order to troubleshoot the issue:

### Test locally

Try to run the container locally and make sure it respond on exposed port successfully:

```bash
docker run --rm --it -p 8080:80 johnlawliet/fastapi_app
curl http://localhost:8080
```

### Check ALB healthcheck

Ensure that Load Balancer healthcheck configured property, and check health status of the application once it get deployed. If your applicaiton is not able to pass healthchecks then ECS will automatically shutdown the container, and because you have Deployment Circuit Breaker in place it won't try to redeploy it.

### Check that ASG works

Another common issue is that ASG spins up a new EC2 instance that never registered in ECS cluster. If this is a case you need to make sure:

1. EC2 instances that launched by ASG has propeply configured security groups, so ECS can access them.
2. Include the following bootstrap script in order to register an instance in the correct ECS cluster:

```bash
cluster_name="fastapiCluster" # should match your ECS cluster name
echo "ECS_CLUSTER=${cluster_name}" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

### Check task resource requirements and EC2 available resources

There is a probablity that your EC2 instance doesn't have enough resources in order to deploy a task. So, make sure that's not the case. You can check resource requirements in the ECS Task definition.

Please let me know if any of these help, or if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for response. However, I have tested locally even after fetching from dockerhub and it works. I see that ASG works because in infrastructure section of clusters, there is the ASG and it shows 1 EC2 container is created. I believe I have allocated sufficient resources 1 vCPU and 1 Gb memory because the application is similar to a "hello world" program so can't require much resources. I set up a new task and its still stuck in "provisioning". Service tab shows active status and 0/1 tasks running

Comment: Does EC2 instance appear on ECS cluster "Infrastructure" tab?

Comment: I had the issue when ASG spins up a EC2 instance but it wasn't regsitered. Also make sure you're using one of ECS-optimized AMI for you EC2 instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html

Comment: I just saw your last screenshot with ECS cluster. It looks good. Did you check ALB healthchecks already?

Comment: I had used the Amazon linux 2 as well as Amazon linux 2023 also. Didn't seem to make a difference. ALB status is active and it shows a listener is registered so incoming request on port 80 gets forwarded to the created target group. But target group is showing that nothing is registered so healthy and unhealthy are at 0. But shouldn't ECS Task be creating the Target group and ALB automatically by itself? I had configured ALB to map port 80 to a target group with IPv4 port 80.

Comment: I created a target group manually directing to IPv4 (since ecs is using awsvpc which only accepts Target group with IPv4 apparently) of public IP used by the ec2 instances. Created the ALB manually and attached the Target group also. I kept the health check route as / since I am using port 80 but target group stays at "Unused". Also, task in ecs is still stuck at provisioning even though target group is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Got issues building images on my MacBook M2 Pro and deploying them on an x86 EC2 instance.
Check your build target.

You attached CloudFormation logs, it would be good to check the Task/container logs to see if you get more details.

You could also turn off the circuit breaker option, at least temporarily as the issue might be linked to its configuration.